# can jquery datatable inject controls (filter,pagination...) into an existing div?

Tags: jquery, datatable

Jquery datatables plugin generates a series of controls (filter,pagination...) directly above or below the actual table. I need the generated filter to be injected into a preexisting div. The sdom option doesn't do the trick, it only generates another such div with that id.

example, using this sdom:

```
"sDom": '<"#myexistingfilterdiv_id"f>'
```

leads to 2 divs with same id (this first is generated, the second is preexisting):

```
<div id="myexistingfilterdiv_id">
generated filter html
</div>

<div id="myexistingfilterdiv_id">
my preexisting empty div
</div>
```

I would like the generated filter html to be generated inside the preexisting div.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do quite what you're asking, but what you can do is detach the `<div id="myexistingfilterdiv_id">` after the datatable is generated and reattach it somewhere else. I'm not sure what else that is likely to break tho. Why do you want to move it?

Comment: I've tried manually moving it around with .html() but it breaks (stops filtering-onchange doesn't fire properly). I don't want it there where it is generated...for example, I want it in a header component.

Comment: Then it sounds like it's time for you to learn some jQuery and go in and modify it to do what you want. That's all I know to tell you since I don't use that plugin...